# Is there a way to query Android's call screening service to check if a specific phone# is spam or not?

Tags: android, spam-prevention

The docs for [CallScreeningService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService) say that it could be used by 3rd-party apps to allow or disallow calls. I'd like to use it in my app (which is NOT going to be set as a default Dialer app) to determine whether a specific phone# is legitimate or not, but I don't see any documentation on how to actually do that.

Is this actually possible?

Comment: The docs say that _as someone implementing a `CallScreeningService`_, you can define the logic for how _you_ want to screen calls. Are you under the impression that there's some default implementation you can use?

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. When I originally read it, I thought that you could have a 3rd-party app that can query the `CallScreeningService`. But that appears to have been just wishful thinking